# Set-Intersection C++ using text file

Tags: c++, set, set-intersection

I am currently writing a code to intersect two sets that are text files. I am new to C++ so there is bad coding. Please tell me what i am missing or mistype in this code. Thanks for helping me.

```
set<string> file1;
set<string> file2;
set<string> ofile;

string data1[] = { "X.txt"};
string data2[]={"Y.txt"};

file1.insert(data1,data1);
file2.insert(data2, data2);

cout<< "file1 is" << file1<<endl;

set_intersection(file1.begin(),file1.end(),file2.begin(),file2.end(),
    inserter(file1, file1.begin()));

 cout<<"file1 * file2 is" << ofile<< endl;
```

Comment: What are `file1` and `file2`? Are you trying to read your input data from the files `x.txt` and `y.txt`?

Comment: Initially I am using files that have data and i am trying to make the files into a set then use set_intersection method.

Comment: So, to try and clarify a bit.  You want the intersection of the filenames, or you want the intersection of the data from inside the two files?  There's no reading from any file in your code, just two filenames.

Comment: I would like to intersect the data inside these two files.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to get integer data from the files `x.txt` and `y.txt`, you could do something like this:

```
typedef int T;

std::ifstream in1("x.txt");
std::ifstream in2("y.txt");

std::set<T> set1{ std::istream_iterator<T>(in1), 
                  std::istream_iterator<T>() };

std::set<T> set2{ std::istream_iterator<T>(in2),
                  std::istream_iterator<T>() };

std::set_intersection(set1.begin(), set1.end(), 
                      set2.begin(), set2.end(),
                      std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

If the contents of the files are something other than integers, you can change the type of `T` to suit (e.g., if you have a set of words, you might want to use `std::string` instead of `int`).

As it stands right now, this just writes the result to standard output. You might want to change that to put the output in some other collection instead.

This also currently puts the initial input data into `std::set`s. Despite the name `set_intersection` the data doesn't really need to be in an `std::set`. It really just needs to be stored in sorted order. You could, for example, put the data into `std::vector`s, then sort them and (if necessary) use `std::unique` to ensure unique elements in each vector. I bring this up primarily because it'll typically run faster and use (substantially) less memory.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, i realize there is so many ways to approach this problem and i got overwhelmed.